# How do I get the aws cli completion to work with zsh on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, zsh, amazon-web-services

I installed aws console cli following the instructions here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-set-up.html#install-bundle-other-os

I want to get completion working with zsh. [The instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-command-completion) say to `source bin/aws_zsh_completer.sh`, which I don't see in the downloaded uncompressed zip installer.

I went ahead and cloned the [git repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) locally.

Still, sourcing the file doesn't work out of the box. When I attempt to autocomplete, I get python errors complaining about missing modules etc. (e.g., `ImportError: No module named awscli.completer`)

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think I managed to get it working but things may have changed in 6 months. I was able to find the .sh file included in the package and sourcing it seemed to work. Maybe time to give it another look. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there might be a misprint in the docs.

The CLI section has the following:

> **zsh** – `source bin/aws_zsh_completer.sh`.
>
> > `% source /usr/local/bin/aws_zsh_completer.sh`

The file `aws_zsh_completer.sh` doesn't live in `/usr/local/bin`, but I found it in `/usr/local/aws/bin` I tried this instead:

> `% source /usr/local/aws/bin/aws_zsh_completer.sh`

I didn't try **tcsh** but I was able to reproduce the same condition with the **bash** instructions.

I am using MacOS at the moment, and I haven't had a chance to check this out on my Linux box.

Comment: On newer versions of ubuntu aws can be installed via `snap`. `snap` isolates your environment from its packages in `/snap`, so the completion extension is to be found here `/snap/aws-cli/current/bin/aws_zsh_completer.sh`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the actual location of the file varies from installation to installation, so it's better to find the exact location of the file in your system:

```
cd /                                                                                              
find -name "aws_zsh*" 
./usr/local/bin/aws_zsh_completer.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out its located here `~/.local/bin/aws_zsh_completer.sh`

```
# add this to your ~/.zshrc 
# aws completion
source  ~/.local/bin/aws_zsh_completer.sh
```

Reload your terminal. --> Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 17.10 with the `awscli` package installed:

```
source /usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions/_awscli
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

Find the `aws_completer`:

```
find / -name aws_completer
```

Add it to the PATH:

```
export PATH=/dir/where/aws_completer/is/:$PATH
```

Load completions:

```
autoload bashcompinit && bashcompinit
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
complete -C '$(which aws_completer)' aws
```

Answer (score 0):

Does including aws in plugins section of ~/.zshrc helps?