# How do I get the aws cli completion to work with zsh on OS X?

Tags: zsh, amazon-web-services

Similar to this question:

[How do I get the aws cli completion to work with zsh on ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/770215/how-do-i-get-the-aws-cli-completion-to-work-with-zsh-on-ubuntu)

This command from the aws-cli documentation did not properly setup auto completion.

`source /usr/local/bin/aws_zsh_completer.sh`

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Common mistake some members make is formatting. Just posting links is not acceptable because they break. Please type out the actual problem and reference with the links. Take a minute to [edit] your question to make it fit the format of this site. Reading **[ask]** may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

To run command completion:

1. Run **bashcompinit** by adding the following autoload line at the end of your **~/.zshrc** profile script.

   *autoload bashcompinit && bashcompinit*
2. Enable command completion, use the built-in command complete.

   *complete -C '/usr/local/bin/aws_completer' aws*
3. Add the commands to **~/.zshrc** to run it each time you open a new shell.
4. Test auto completiion

aws sTAB - should display something similar to this:
[Test Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqkie.png)

For other shells, review [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-completion.html).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
source /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_aws
$echo 'source /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_aws' >> ~/.zshrc
```

[Source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/osx-installing-the-aws-command-line-interface-using-brew/)

Comment: I get this error on my mac using zsh -> 
9:41:24 Fri 25 code 1013:13-127$ source /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_aws
source: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_aws
9:44:03 Fri 25 code 1014:14-127$

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS

- Find the path of the aws_completer using the command
  `which aws_completer` and copy the output path
- Then find the running shell using the command `echo $SHELL`
- Open the shell file (mine is zsh - ~/.zshrc)
- Add the below lines in your shell file

  `complete -C '<add_the_path_copied_from_first_step>' aws`
- Then use the `source` command to update the file changes. For example: `source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score -1):

You need to have the aws_completer in your path for this to work correctly. Another option would be to modify the aws_zsh_completer.sh script.

```
complete -C aws_completer aws

complete -C <pathtoaws_completer>/aws_completer aws
```

Comment: `complete` is a bash thing.  The question is about zsh.

Comment: @JohnMee Wrong, `complete` is relevant to `zsh` as well, based on AWS CLI autocompletion docs, plus docs for other autocompletion tools